# After ABP BoilerPlate upgrade to 6.3, IAsyncBackgroundJob can not be invoked

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Our platform is currently on v6.2.0 of abp Boilerplate and after upgrading to v6.3.0, our jobs are not being triggered because the following error is raised. I downgraded back to v6.2.0 with no code change other than a version change and our jobs then work fine.

I plan to dig through the V6.3.0 source this weekend but if something has already figured out a similar issue, please let me know.

Error:

```
{"The type `Abp.BackgroundJobs.IAsyncBackgroundJob`1[AI.BackgroundJobCoordinators.BackgroundJobs.ArgsDto.FeatureDeterminatorBackgroundJobArgsDto]` must be derived from the `AI.BackgroundJobCoordinators.BackgroundJobs.FeatureDeterminatorBackgroundJob` type. (Parameter 'type')"}
```

Comment: Bug fix not released yet: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/6087

Comment: Hey @aaron, okay I see the issue. I'll track the PR and if it runs behind, I will most probably fix it locally to get things working and then see when it lands in a release. Thanks for the heads up, saved me a few hours this weekend!

Answer (score 0):

V6.3.0 in error uses **TJob instead of TArgs to check job type**.
This has been corrected in release V6.3.1.
See https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/pull/6087